# How to debug clang using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, llvm, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to debug clang using eclipse. I have put a break point in clang/lib/lex/preprocessor.cpp at the preprocessor's constructor.

1. I have set a "test.c" file as an argument in the debug configurations.
2. Went to Run-> Debug As-> Local C/C++ Application.
3. It asked "Choose local application to debug". I chose "clang" and clicked OK.
4. It started building the code. build completed.
5. Stopped at main() in the debug window. (No source available for main())
6. After some step overs, it says "terminated: gdb Debugger (Exited. Exit code=255)"

I am not taken to the clang code (preprocessor code). can someone please tell me how to debug the clang code.? I want to see the code flow in clang. and how clang is constructing the AST.

Answer (score 3):

Clang binary in fact contains two apps: driver and compiler frontend itself. The latter is executed via -cc1 cmdline option. So, just add -v to clang command line to see the actual sequence of tool invocation, grab the frontend cmdline (the one containing -cc1) and use this cmdline for debugging.

Comment: I am not trying to debug my code using clang. I want to debug the clang's code. open the LLVM Source as "Makefile Project" in eclipse and debug it.

Comment: Yes, I written the instruction for clang itself.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem - you are missing the -g flag (enable debug info) when you are building your binaries.
When running the cmake run it with the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE option:

```
cmake -G "Eclipse <CDT_Version> - Unix Makefiles" -D_ECLIPSE_VERSION=<eclipse_version> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug  <llvm_source_path>
```

example :

```
cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -D_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.4 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug  ../llvm/
```

hope that this helps.